# Ordering a list according to hierarchy

Tags: python, sorting

I've a list

```
a = ["Asia/Pacific", "North America", "India,Asia/Pacific", "China, Asia/Pacific", "New Delhi, India, Asia/Pacific", "Bangalore, India,Asia/Pacific",  "Shangai, China, Asia/Pacific", "US, North America", "New York, US, North America"]
```

I want it to be sorted in such as way that all the leaf and parent node comes together. For eg:-

```
a = ["Asia/Pacific", "India,Asia/Pacific", "New Delhi, India, Asia/Pacific", "Bangalore, India,Asia/Pacific",  "China, Asia/Pacific", "Shangai, China, Asia/Pacific", "North America", "US, North America", "New York, US, North America"]
```

To make it more clear, it should follow a tree structure like -

```
Asia/Pacific
   India
       Bangalore
            Sarjapur Road
            MG Road
       Mumbai
             Santa Cruz
   China
       Beijing
       Shanghai

North America
   USA
   Canada
   Mexico
```

How can I go about?

Comment: You should redesign your data structure. Nested lists or dicts instead of a messy string-syntax in a list.

Comment: You just got your final answer from @NilsWerner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a key that reflects the structure; split on comma and reverse:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda p: map(str.strip, p.split(',')[::-1]))
```

This sorts the last component alphabetically, then for the same region, sorts the country alphabetically, etc. The `str.strip` mapping is needed to remove the extra spaces.

Demo:

```
>>> a = ["Asia/Pacific", "North America", "India,Asia/Pacific", "China, Asia/Pacific", "New Delhi, India, Asia/Pacific", "Bangalore, India,Asia/Pacific",  "Shangai, China, Asia/Pacific", "US, North America", "New York, US, North America"]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda p: map(str.strip, p.split(',')[::-1]))
['Asia/Pacific', 'China, Asia/Pacific', 'Shangai, China, Asia/Pacific', 'India,Asia/Pacific', 'Bangalore, India,Asia/Pacific', 'New Delhi, India, Asia/Pacific', 'North America', 'US, North America', 'New York, US, North America']
```